# Short xPath in R for use with RSelenium

Tags: r, rselenium, xml2

I have a problem when using `findElement()` from `RSelenium` with xPath on this [page](http://www.sonova.com/en/media/news) where the xPath expression for an element is very long, i.e. the element is nested deeply (I use firefox for the remote driver). `findElement()` works fine on the [page](http://www.sonova.com/en/media/news) if I use a short xPath expression that I get from inspecting the element e.g. in Google Chrome. However, in R (as far as I know) I can only retrieve the long xPath expression using for example `xml_path()` from package `xml2`. Is there a way to get a short xPath expression in R to work around this problem?

```
library(RSelenium)
url = "http://www.sonova.com/en/media/news"    

remDr = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

ShortxPath = "//*[@id='edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn']"
LongxPath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"
```

`remDr$findElement(using='xpath', ShortxPath)`works fine but with `remDr$findElement(using='xpath', LongxPath)` I get the following error message:

```
Error: Summary: NoSuchElement
Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just curious.  If you can get the element with the shorter XPath why do you need the long one to work.  Also, when scraping using the id life you did in the sort one is much more robust to website changes.

Comment: I can get the short path manually - which I did in this case. But if I search for an element in the DOM that meets some criteria and then try to fetch its xpath I am not able to get the short version. Which is what I am looking for. I could also fetch the element's id but not all elements support this attribute... so I guess this won't work either :(.

Comment: If you use chrome there is an extension called SelectorGadget that I use all the time.  Also, you can use name, id, and a lot of other identifiers to get you past those divs.  Nevertheless, sometimes you end up in no man's land and need to use a long path so I see where you are coming from.

Comment: Try using other options like css or partial link text. What information exactly are you trying to scrape from the page that you mentioned?  if you use `findElement ( using = "css element"," #edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn span") ` I guess the same works.

Comment: The page is just an example but basically I need to be able to click an element which I identified in the DOM. As far as I know, the problem with other inputs than xpath for `findElement` is that 1) I cannot retrieve these in R, 2) they are not necessarily available for every element, or 3) I have to manually check the page (eg using selectorGadget). This leaves me with xpath but it seems that the xpath expression I retrieve using `xml2::xml_path` can be too long for `findElement`...

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `RSelenium`. This is the AJAX/XHR request that's made when a popup is selected:

```
httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "http://www.sonova.com/en/views/ajax", 
    add_headers(Origin = "http://www.sonova.com", 
        `Accept-Encoding` = "gzip, deflate", 
        `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
        `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36", 
        Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", 
        Referer = "http://www.sonova.com/en/media/news", 
        `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest", 
        Connection = "keep-alive", 
        DNT = "1"), body = list(`date_filter[value][year]` = "2016", 
        view_name = "news", view_display_id = "page_2", 
        view_args = "", view_path = "media/news", 
        view_base_path = "media/news", 
        view_dom_id = "4f36b0b6d279ba22a46fda6b45ccdd1e", 
        pager_element = "0", `ajax_html_ids[]` = "fit-vids-style", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "style-1-cropbar-clipper", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "logo-title-wrapper", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "logo-title", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "logo-title-logo", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "logo-title-delimiter", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "logo-title-slogan", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-superfish-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "superfish-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4047-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4046-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3116-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3040-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3048-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7129-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3118-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-2960-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3041-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4065-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7067-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3693-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5652-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3045-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3046-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3047-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-2716-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4048-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-2536-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-2796-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-2797-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7046-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3966-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3365-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3367-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5651-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7101-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3098-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3122-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5654-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7107-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7106-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3102-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5661-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3106-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3108-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3050-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3051-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3053-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3120-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3054-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7421-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3056-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4067-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4068-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3062-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3064-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3066-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3068-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3072-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3074-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3079-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3076-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3080-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7068-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4708-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4049-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3691-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-1890-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3965-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6074-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7045-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7069-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6186-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7098-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3125-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-4050-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5632-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7042-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5636-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7410-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5634-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7411-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5639-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5638-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7049-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-3284-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7050-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5641-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-5646-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7065-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6359-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6372-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6188-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6360-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6362-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6374-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6370-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6376-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6364-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6367-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-6368-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "menu-7125-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-apachesolr-panels-search-form", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "apachesolr-panels-search-block", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-apachesolr-panels-search-form", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-actions", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-submit", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "main-content", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-block-24", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "views-exposed-form-news-page-2", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-date-filter-wrapper", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-date-filter-value-wrapper", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-date-filter-value", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-date-filter-value", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-date-filter-value-year", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_0", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_2", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_3", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_4", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_5", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_6", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_7", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_8", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_9", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_10", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_11", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_12", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_13", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit_date_filter_value_year_chzn_o_14", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "edit-submit-news", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-menu-block-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-panels-mini-social-media-sidebar-media", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "mini-panel-social_media_sidebar_media", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-panels-mini-footer-teaser-media", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "mini-panel-footer_teaser_media", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-block-14", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-locale-language", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-menu-block-2", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-block-1", 
        `ajax_html_ids[]` = "block-block-30", 
        `ajax_page_state[theme]` = "sonova", 
        `ajax_page_state[theme_token]` = "iUh534BYiVjPdWDZAWTaoKWaP7PSCw9itl7qz8ZHnk0", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][0]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][1]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][2]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][3]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][4]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][5]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/system/system.base.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/system/system.menus.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/system/system.messages.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/system/system.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/field/field.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/mollom/mollom.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][modules/node/node.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/search/search.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/custom/social_media/css/social-media-icons.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/user/user.theme.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/omega/css/modules/user/user.base.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/libraries/chosen/chosen/chosen.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/chosen/css/chosen-drupal.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/custom/custom/js/iealert/style.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/panels/css/panels.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/views_slideshow.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/4c9817ec89d2eea25e2d03fdbe3caf01.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/3e409a6b8a8403f7c6fad84e85cb2c4c_2.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/7e4a5ede216a8e29a390a3d19204cb02_5.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/b28b41cf976f7b854611d66497c6663a_2.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/43131ccf35fa0c1e323794d8af618676_1.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/panels/plugins/layouts/flexible/flexible.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][public://ctools/css/c4399fe142d4864f78b0cc8cd615f450_1.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/modules/flexslider/assets/css/flexslider_img.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/libraries/flexslider/flexslider.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/libraries/superfish/css/superfish-smallscreen.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/sonova/css/reset.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/sonova/css/styles.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[css][sites/all/themes/sonova/css/print.css]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][0]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][1]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/chosen/chosen.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][misc/jquery.once.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][misc/drupal.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/misc/jquery.form.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][misc/ajax.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/jquery_update/js/jquery_update.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/custom/custom/js/common.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/omega/libraries/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/libraries/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/custom/custom/js/iealert.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/iframe/iframe.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/panels/js/panels.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/js/views_slideshow.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/ctools/js/auto-submit.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/views/js/base.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][misc/progress.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/views/js/ajax_view.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/jquery.iframeResizer.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/libraries/superfish/superfish.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/modules/superfish/superfish.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/jquery.stacktable.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/jquery.browser.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/general.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/jquery.fitvids.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/js/jquery.backgroundSize.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/libraries/selectivizr/selectivizr.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[js][sites/all/themes/sonova/libraries/respond/respond.min.js]` = "1", 
        `ajax_page_state[jquery_version]` = "1.7"), 
    encode = "form")
```

Figure out the params & now you can use R w/o browser instrumentation or XPath hacking.

This was created via [`curlconverter`](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/curlconverter)

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion! I am not familiar with this approach but I will try to work through it...

Comment: Sorry, this approach is really new to me and I am pretty stuck here. How do you work with this response object? I am also not quite clear what you mean by the params. May be you can give me a further hint on that. Thank you very much!