# R - How can I run javascript button on website to display all values for scraping

Tags: javascript, r, web, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data on a site that shows products 1-30 unless I press "List all" button. This button is JavaScript and doesn't change the URL when I run it. I am currently using the rvest package in R to do this.

```
  page <- paste("https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/shopping/shop.aspx?catid=150200350")
  page <- read_html(page)
```

I have looked at some other posts and it mentions using RSelenium package but I'd prefer if there was another way.

EDIT - I have now got to this code below thanks to Jack's help, but am experiencing two issues.

1) Some pages don't show all products even though we press the button "ListAll". It will show the first 200 and then you have to navigate through pages for the next 200 etc. e.g. on this page https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/shopping/shop.aspx?catid=150200275

2) In my loop, if the code can't detect a "ListAll" element (i.e. if there are less than 30 products, the code throws an error. Anyone know how to avoid that in the loop? Pseudo (if no ListAll element is present, skip ListAll and continue running)

```
checkForServer()
startServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver()
mybrowser$open()

while(i < 67){

  # Navigate to page
  mybrowser$navigate(paste("https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/shopping/shop.aspx?catid=150200275"))

  # Show all products
  ListAll <- mybrowser$findElement("class", "listAllText")
  ListAll$clickElement()

  # Navigate to next page (only goes to second page, when run again, it goes back to the first page as it is the first "unselected" class it detects.
  ListAll <- mybrowser$findElement("class", "unselected")
  ListAll$clickElement()


  # Take it slow
  Sys.sleep(7)
  outhtml <- mybrowser$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*")
  out<-outhtml$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]

  # Parse with RCurl
  doc<-htmlParse(out, encoding = "UTF-8")
  doc
  # Scrape product info
  productRaw <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*[@class = 'productTitle']")
  products <- sapply(productRaw, xmlValue)

  priceRaw <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*[@class = 'divProductPrice BodyText Style3']")
  price <- sapply(priceRaw, xmlValue)

  pricePerUnitRaw <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*[@class = 'divProductPricePerUnit BodyText Style2']")
  pricePerUnit <- sapply(pricePerUnitRaw, xmlValue)

  barcodeRaw <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*[@class = 'productImage']//a[@href]//img[@src]")
  barcode <- sapply(barcodeRaw, xmlValue)
  barcode <- sapply(barcodeRaw,function(x) xmlAttrs(x)["src"])

  final <- rbind(final, data.frame(Products = products, 
                                   Price = price, UnitPrice = pricePerUnit, Barcode = barcode))
  i=i+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you would prefer another way but I wanted to throw up the RSelenium solution so you can see it.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)

# Start Selenium server
checkForServer()
startServer()

remDr <- remoteDriver()

remDr$open()

# Navigate to page
remDr$navigate("https://shop.supervalu.ie/shopping/shopping/shop.aspx?catid=150200350")

# Snag the html
ListAll <- remDr$findElement("class", "listAllText")
ListAll$clickElement()

# Take it slow
Sys.sleep(.50)

outhtml <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*")
out<-outhtml$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]

# Parse with RCurl
doc<-htmlParse(out, encoding = "UTF-8")

# just scraping a bit for example
gg <- getNodeSet(doc, "//*[@class = 'productTitle']")

sapply(gg, xmlValue)
```

hrbrmstr might have some ajax magic that you can use. Check out his answer to a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554446/short-xpath-in-r-for-use-with-rselenium?noredirect=1#comment58800139_35554446)

Comment: I went down the RSelenium route, seemed the best way. However, 2 additional issues have come up. 1) One of the pages has more than 200 products (list all button only shows first 200) but there are page 2 etc.. I can't work out how to choose the next page navigation. 
2) I have a loop cycling through pages but when there is no "list all" element the code breaks (less than 30 products means no "list all"). Any ideas on how to avoid the loop breaking? I've added to my code above what I currently have.